# DialogFragment doesn't show up in the listener

Tags: android, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I know there is one question with same title, but my scenario is a bit complex. In FragmentA, once click the button will start a new activity to show FragmentB, if then click one button in FragmentB, i need to dismiss FragmentB and go back to FragmentA and show DialogFragmentC. What i do is define one listener in FragmentB and implement it in FragmentA.

The sample snippet is as below:

```
class FragmentA extends Fragment implements FragmentBDelegate {
    .......
    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked() {
        DialogFragment popup = new DialogFragmentC();
        popup.show(((AppCompatActivity)getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
    }
    ......
}

class FragmentB extends Fragment{
    ......
    private void onButtonClicked(View v) {
        getActivity().finish();// to dismiss current activity
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.onButtonClicked();
        }
    }

    public interface FragmentBDelegate {
        void onButtonClicked();
    }

    ......
}
```

Why the DialogFragment doesn't show up? If listener cannot implement this requirement, how to implement?

Comment: A bit confused . Does `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` belongs to same Activity or not ?

Comment: I think they belong to different activities.

Comment: Did you try to debug? Did you check if the `onButtonClicked` function is being invoked after returning to `FragmentA`?

Comment: @ReazMurshed it's invoked. the code executed. But the popup won't show.

Comment: How did you implements interface b/w two different Activities ? This is not how you communicate b/w Activities . Use Conventional Approach instead which is `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: @ADM i'm maintaining the project, there is another method in the listener to inform the FragmentA the selected item from FragmentB. So i just add another method to inform the FragmentA to show popup. Will try to see the `startActivityForResult()`

Comment: Try check logs when you are using listener. It is possible that you are doing transaction in paused state of `ActivityA`. `commit()`  transaction will not succeed. Because `dialogFragment.show()` uses `commit()`. I can not test your scenario right now but you should check it also see `commitAllowingStateLoss()`. Also look into source of `DialogFragment`.

Comment: @ADM i replace `commit()` with `commitAllowingStateLoss()` in one customShow(). it works.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@ADM's comment guide me to one workaround. I define one `showWithStateLoss()` method with `commitAllowingStateLoss()` to commit the FragmentTransaction in `DialogFragmentC`. Then it works.

```
public void showWithStateLoss(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss(); //original it's commit()
}
```

Comment: Great you got it. I just wanna make one point here . Callbacks are not lifecycle aware So its better if you use lifecycle aware approach when working with Components and Lifecycle aware stuff. In that case it should be `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: I see, but the project is not easy to use the `startActivityForResult()`. so far i will use this dirty solution first.

Comment: Yeah . That was just a point . Mark your answer as Accepted .

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** (maybe you can, but should not) use callback method between **different** activities.

If this is exactly what you need to do, you need to start 2nd activity for result with `startActivityForResult()`. Then decide if you want to show dialog based on 2nd activity result. `FragmentB` will set result rather than trying to call 1st activity's callback.

Comment: Maybe it's not good practice, but actually **can**.There is another method in the listener which is to inform FragmentA the selected item from FragmentB. It works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.